# Join two endpoints of one line to two points in points table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, geospatial

I have a table of line segments (no multilines) and table of points that I need to join (eventually into a view) using geometry: LineID, FromPtID, ToPtID.  The problem I am having is that I want to use the point geometry twice - once for each end of the line - a "FromGeoPt" and "ToGeoPt"

```
    SELECT TOP 100
(SELECT top 1
    [CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint.Geometry as FromGeoPt
    FROM
    [CadData].dbo.CleanLines ,
    [CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint
    WHERE 
    SurveyPoint.Geometry.STEquals(CleanLines.Geom.STStartPoint())=1
    ),
(SELECT TOP 1
    [CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint.Geometry as ToGeoPt
    FROM
    [CadData].dbo.CleanLines ,
    [CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint
    WHERE 
    SurveyPoint.Geometry.STEquals(CleanLines.Geom.STEndPoint())=1
    ),
[CadData].dbo.CleanLines.FeatId as LINEid,
CleanLines.Geom.STEndPoint() as ENDPT,
CleanLines.Geom.STStartPoint() as STPT,
[CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint.ObjectId as SURVEYPOINTOBJECTid,
[CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint.Name as SurveyPointName,
[CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint.[Description],
[CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint.Geometry

FROM
[CadData].dbo.CleanLines ,
[CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint

WHERE       
(
CleanLines.Geom.STEndPoint().STEquals(TOGEOPT) = 1
and
CleanLines.Geom.STStartPoint().STEquals(FROMGEOPT) = 1
)
```

The main problem I have with this select is that I need to use a @variable instead of TOGEOPT and FROMGEOPT in the WHERE clause but I don't know how.  I tried moving the subqueries above as follows but it just gives me the same line 100 times

```
    Declare @FromGeoPt as GEOMETRY
    Declare @ToGeoPt as GEOMETRY

SET @FromGeoPt = 
    (SELECT TOP 1
        [CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint.Geometry as FROMGEOPT
    FROM
    [CadData].dbo.CleanLines ,
    [CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint

    WHERE 
    SurveyPoint.Geometry.STEquals(CleanLines.Geom.STStartPoint())=1
    )


SET @ToGeoPt = 
    (SELECT TOP 1
        [CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint.Geometry as TOGEOPT
    FROM
    [CadData].dbo.CleanLines ,
    [CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint

    WHERE 
    SurveyPoint.Geometry.STEquals(CleanLines.Geom.STEndPoint())=1
    )

SELECT TOP 100
    @ToGeoPt AS TOGEO,
    @FromGeoPt AS FROMGEO,
    [CadData].dbo.CleanLines.FeatId as LINEid,
    CleanLines.Geom.STEndPoint() as ENDPT,
    CleanLines.Geom.STStartPoint() as STPT,
    [CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint.ObjectId as SURVEYPOINTOBJECTid,
    [CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint.Name as SurveyPointName,
    [CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint.[Description],
    [CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint.Geometry

    FROM
    [CadData].dbo.CleanLines ,
    [CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint

    WHERE
    (
    CleanLines.Geom.STEndPoint().STEquals(@ToGeoPt) = 1
    and
    CleanLines.Geom.STStartPoint().STEquals(@FromGeoPt) = 1
    )
```

(I obviously have some topology issues because I get an error if I don't use "TOP 1" when finding the point that matches the start/end points of each line.)

I have played around with JOIN, but have the same essential problem: Using two points to join to one line.  The following uses only the start point.

```
  Select top 100
  CadData.dbo.CleanLines.FeatId as LINEid
  , CadData.Survey.SurveyPoint.ObjectId as SurveyPointID
  , CadData.Survey.SurveyPoint.Name
  , CadData.Survey.SurveyPoint.[Description]
  from
  CadData.dbo.CleanLines inner join CadData.Survey.SurveyPoint on 
    CleanLines.Geom.STStartPoint().STEquals(SurveyPoint.Geometry) = 1
  order by LINEid asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `JOIN` twice to the points table if you want start and end values on the same output row:

```
  FROM CadData.dbo.CleanLines 
  JOIN CadData.Survey.SurveyPoint start_point
    ON CleanLines.Geom.STStartPoint().STEquals(start_point.Geometry) = 1
  JOIN CadData.Survey.SurveyPoint end_point 
    ON CleanLines.Geom.STEndPoint().STEquals(end_point.Geometry) = 1
  order by LINEid asc
```

Or expand your `JOIN` criteria if you want start and end values on separate output rows:

```
  FROM CadData.dbo.CleanLines 
  JOIN CadData.Survey.SurveyPoint 
    ON CleanLines.Geom.STStartPoint().STEquals(SurveyPoint .Geometry) = 1
      OR CleanLines.Geom.STEndPoint().STEquals(SurveyPoint .Geometry) = 1
  order by LINEid asc
```

May have to adjust `JOIN` criteria in both of above, but the idea is sound.

Comment: Thanks.  I never would have thought about using two aliases on the same table to separate the From/To points.  Also had to remember that SELECT can use an alias even when it is defined afterwards.